# Relative path and mod_rewrite issue

Tags: mod-rewrite

Have a trouble with mod_rewrite.
I want :

htp://example.com/a/some_text -> htp://example.com/?p1=some_text and
htp://example.com/b/some_text -> htp://example.com/?p1=some_text

So, I type:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)\/(a|b)\/(.*)$

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?fsearch=$2 [QSA]
```

and get wrong relative paths in css, such as htp://example.com/a/CSS/main.css instead of htp://example.com/CSS/main.css. And get nothing in $2 too.

Help, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$2` tries to pick the second capture group of the `RewriteRules` subject, but there is only one! You probably mean `%2` which picks from the `RewriteCond`...

Since you only append a query string in your `RewriteRule` the original URI (path) is left untouched.

You can simplify the pattern in the `RewriteRule` since you are not interested in the subject anyway.

This is probably what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)\/(a|b)\/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ /?fsearch=%3 [QSA]
```

Much better however would be to rewrite directly to whatever script you actually want to process the request to safe another rewriting round to find the index document, so something like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)\/(a|b)\/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ /index.php?fsearch=%3 [QSA]
```

And *unless* you decide to use the first capture group in the `RewriteCond` you can also simplify that further:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/(a|b)\/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ /index.php?fsearch=%2 [QSA]
```

Comment: arkascha, now it works as example.com/index.php?fsearch=a and the problem with paths still exists.

Comment: And "the problem with paths" is what exactly?

Comment: Reading through your comment I assume you tested an outdated version of my answer. Note that I updated (fixed) it a few times.

Comment: Your 3rd code puts right parameter, but I still get wrong relative paths. It means logo located in example.com/media/logo.png is not found cause this path turns to example.com/a/media/logo.png

Comment: Sorry, it is unclear what you actually mean by "logo located in  ..:" and "this path turns to...". Please be _precise_ in what you ask, so that we can easily understand it. That is in your own interest, everything else is frustrating...

Comment: I am very grateful to you for your patience. I say that as a result of a redirect from Listing 3 is a substitution of references to the logo and CSS, and now these links look like example.com/a/CCS/main.css and example.com/a/media/logo.png instead of correct links example.com/CCS/main.css and example.com/media/logo.png.

Comment: All fine, don't get me wrong, I only wanted to enhance the precision in this exchange :-)

Comment: I am still confused by what you state: rewriting does not somehow alter links you send out somewhere, coded in some html page or similar. That is why I don't understand what you are trying to say. If the incoming requests ask for `/a/CCS/main.css` and you consider that wrong, then you have to change the links. That is nothing rewriting can do for you. Rewriting can only rewrite _incoming_ requests to new internal paths. The only situation where such rewriting effects the outside is if you use an "external redirection" (`R=301`) or similar which is not the case above.